# vuejs props - parent variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this props in a vue page (apps.vue)

```js
props: {
  vote: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => {
      return {};
    }
  },
},
```

as far as I know the property "props" is used to pass data from parent to children. I think `apps.vue` is the child (right ?)

I want how can I find the parent file of that property because I need to check its variables

exp: `this.vote.good`

Comment: Find where your component is used and check the attributes, eg `<Apps :vote="{good: 'value'}">`

Comment: @Phil is this the only syntax I would find ? :propsName="{variable: 'value'}" ?

Comment: Not necessarily, it could also be defined within a [render function](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html).

Comment: @Phil there isn't a way to know the name of the component from where that props is called ? I want to check all the variables declared inside it

Comment: Use the Vue dev tools browser extension, it will show you the component hierarchy

Answer (score -1):

apps.vue

```
<Apps :vote="data" />
```

children component

in templete

```
{{ data }}
```

in script

```
this.data
```

and ...

```
export default {
  props: ['vote']
}
```

or

```
export default {
  props: {
     vote: {
         require: true,
         type: String,
         default: ''
     }
  }
}
```